# aws ecs service security

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ecs

I'm new to aws ecs service and would like to know about the security inside ecs service.

I'm creating an ecs task which includes two docker container (A and B). A spring-boot application is running on container B and works as a gateway to the backend services. No login/security is necessary to access this app from container A .. so I can invoke like http://localhost:8080/middleware/ ...  and then one of the servlet generates a saml token and invoke backend services by adding this token as authorization header. All looks good and works fine. However, a couple developers indicated this design has a flaw. "Even if ecs service running in SecurityGroup and only an entry point port is open, it is possible for hacker to install malwares onto ec2 instance on which two containers are running, and this malware can invoke the spring-boot app running in container B which is a security breach"

I'm not sure if what I heard from my co-workers is true?  The security in aws is not strong enough to communicate using localhost without security between containers??  If anyone tells me about this, it would be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

Security and Compliance is a [shared responsibility between AWS and the customer](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/) .

In general, AWS is responsible for the security of the overall infrastructure of the cloud, and the customer is responsible for the security of the application, instances and of their data.

For a service like ECS, it is categorized as Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) and, as such, requires the customer to perform all of the necessary security configuration and related management tasks.

As the customer  you would normally secure an EC2 type ECS load by hardening the instance, use  proper security groups, implement VPC security features eg NACLS and private subnets, use least privilege IAM users/roles, while also applying Docker security best practices to secure the containers and images.

Note: Docker itself is a complicated system, and there is no one trick you can use to maintain Docker container security. Rather you have to think broadly  about ways to secure your Docker containers, and harden your container environment at multiple levels, including the instance itself. Doing this is the only way to ensure that you can have all the benefits of Docker, without leaving yourself at risk of major security issues.

Some answers to your specific questions and comments:

> it is possible for hacker to install malwares onto ec2 instance on which two containers are running, and this malware

If hackers have penetrated your instance and have installed malware, then you have a major security flaw at the instance level, not at the container level. Harden and secure your instances to insure your perimeter is protected. This is the customer's responsibility.

> The security in aws is not strong enough to communicate using localhost without security between containers?

AWS infrastructure is secure and compliant and maintains certified compliance with security standards like PCI and HIPPA. You don't need to worry about security at the infrastructure level for this reason, that is AWS responsibility.

> No login/security is necessary to access this app from container A .. so I can invoke like http://localhost:8080/middleware

This is certainly not ideal security, and again it is customer responsibility to secure such application endpoints. You should consider implementing basic authentication here - this can be implemented by virtually any web or app server. You could also implement IP whitelisting so API calls can only be accepted from the container A network subnet.

For more information on ECS security see
[Security in Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/security.html)

For more information on AWS infrastructure security see [Amazon Web Services: Overview of Security Processes](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your colleagues observation is correct.

There is very good possibility of such hacks. But, AWS does provide many different ways in which you can secure your own servers and containers.

1. Using nested security groups in Public Subnet

In this scenario, AWS allows port access to particular security group rather than an IP address / CIDR range. So only resources having particular security group nested can access those ports while no one from outside can access them.

2. Using Virtual Private Cloud

In this scenario host your all the instances and ecs containers in private subnet and allow only the access to particular port via NAT gateway for public access, in such scenario your instance won't be directly vulnerable to attacks.